# Why does constructor of HttpClient in Angular not need param, when I instanstiate it via constructor of other class, but needs via new?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to make a static method for instanstiating an object of class, but faced an issue.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export MyClass {
  // Case 1
  public static init(): MyClass {
    return this(new HttpClient(***), ....); // Need to pass new HttpClient() instead ***
  }

  // Case 2
  public constructor(private http: HttpClient, ....) {} // Need to pass nothing
}
```

Why I have to pass argument in case 1, but in case 2 not? And how to solve my problem?

Comment: "*when I instanstiate it via constructor*" - because that is not what is happening in case 2. All you do is declare a function parameter named `http`. No instantiation is happening, no constructor is called.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

This happens thanks to **dependency injection**. Angular says:

> Dependency injection, or DI, is a design pattern in which a class
> requests dependencies from external sources rather than creating them

In your case you don't need to "create" that resource but simply use it, and for that dependency injection comes to your aid

I recommend you take a look at the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#dependency-injection-in-angular) of Angular, always very clear and quite useful!

> And how to solve my problem?

If you just need to use HttpClient, do as in `// Case 2` and **without the need to initialize anything**; otherwise, if you can **please explain better what your goal** is and how you can't achieve it so we can help you, thanks!

---

Let me know if you have any doubts ;)

Comment: I need to implement init method. What is a better way?

Comment: @mark but what are you doing? a service, a component or what? for what purpose?

Comment: I'm doing a class for using it inside other component. In component it suppose to be something like this const myClass = MyClass.init();

Comment: @mark okay so basically you are making a service, that is a class that provides certain functions to a component. In Angular you **don't do** `myClass = MyClass.init()` but we use **dependency injection**, so in the constructor of the component you put `constructor(private myClass: MyClass) {}` and automatically the `constructor` of myClass is executed (as if you had initialized it)

read more about that here -> https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services